# what does it mean by "glean somebody"?

Tags: meaning

> Then, at Winter Conclave, your friend Rowan shall be ordained, and, as
> has already been stipulated, he shall **glean you**.
>
> They passed an elementary school one day as it was letting out, and
> Citra had a sinking feeling that she would **glean one of the students**.

here are two sentences from a novel ,which in the title *scythe* (written by   Neal Shusterman),I'm sorry that I cannot  provide  with more information as I didn't exactly know which chapter those examples derived from.but I think it's totally okay since no context given doesn't really matter much here.

of course I had already looked up the word"glean",it essentially  means to gather some tiny pieces bit by bit,such as grains left on the field, or information about anything.
So, how to "glean somebody"? in this two examples, however, it gives me a sense of "to kill somebody"(probably by means of a scythe as what the title means to?).
please help me with it.

Comment: Looks like a sci-fi title.  My guess is *glean* has something to do with the Scythes harvesting people.  The word likely retains its original meaning but is used in a unique way.  Do the Scythes *gather/harvest* the students?  It's difficult to provide a useful answer without understanding the larger context of the story.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not a regular use of the word glean.  It is a special euphemism invented by Shusterman for his book.

He explains this in the very first section of the book.  You can read it https://www.onlinereadfreebooks.com/en/Scythe-568213/1

He explains that in his future world "glean" mean to "kill" (when committed by a priesthood known as "Scythes")

There is *no way* to know this unless you read the book from the start.

Comment: thank you ,that helps a lot!